# DrawableGameComponent does not respond to my taps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I've created a basic `DrawableGameComponent` and implemented `Update` and `Draw` function. My Update method looks like this:

```
        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (this.state != ComponentState.Hidden)
            {
                if (this.state == ComponentState.Visible)
                {   
                    while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
                    {
                        GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

                        if (gesture.GestureType == GestureType.Tap)
                        {
                            Point tapLocation = new Point((int)gesture.Position.X, (int)gesture.Position.Y);

                            // TODO: handle input here!
                            this.state = ComponentState.Hidden; // test
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

And I have enabled the following gestures in the constructor:

```
TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap | GestureType.VerticalDrag;
```

The problem here is that it does not react on the if test when I check for Tap. Is there something I need to do with the DrawableGameComponent?

Comment: Have you tried to remove your checks of the Component visibility? Your gesture related code looks fine assuming you aren't reading them from else where.

Comment: @Layoric if I set a breakpoint on the while-loop it hits.

Comment: is 'TouchPanel.ReadGesture();' any where else in your code? another component also being processed?

Comment: @Layoric This drawablegamecomponent is ment as a overlay-type-menu, I have MenuScreen running under the component. guess that one reads the gestures first? but how do I solve this? how is the microsoft adcontrol able to fetch taping (for instance)

Comment: Not sure how the adcontrol works, it's a bit of a strange one as I'm pretty sure it uses something similar to XAML WebView control (Windows 8 uses it this way), so not a typical control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your gestures are being read else where in the code and when your provided code checks for `TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable` it is false as they have all been read.

A common way around this is to create an InputState class that wraps all your input code for the different screens you might have. This pattern (and a few other good ones) can be found in the [GameState Management Sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) that microsoft provide in their educational section. This sample is a really good starting point for any project as it takes care of screen management, input etc.

Hope that helps.